# Generating a list of random integers (from -1000 to 1000), the number of integers in the list are determined by user input

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, random, integer

I have looked through other questions but nothing seems to work. The user chooses how many numbers are in the list and they should be between -1000 and 1000. I tried using two for loops, one displaying the random number and another around that loop repeating the number of time the user enters. For now I tried to just get the loop to work with positive integers up to 1000. When using system print out it finally worked but using the GUI I just get one random number. I used an `ArrayList` because I thought it'd let me add to it with each loop.

```
int a;
private void btnSortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    try {
        a = Integer.parseInt(txtSort.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        lbl1.setText("Please enter a proper integer");     
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1;i<=1000; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
   
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++) {
        txtpane1.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
    }
}
```

`txtSort` is the textfield the program gets the number of integers and I'm using Apache NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly your problem!

1. You want to generate random numbers user input times which lie between -1000 to 1000.
2. Then you want to display these all numbers in a `Text Pane` (Your GUI).

Please look at the following code: (Modified your code)

```
    int a;
    private void btnSortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            a = Integer.parseInt(txtSort.getText());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
            lbl1.setText("Please enter a proper integer");
        }

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i=1;i<=a; i++) {
            int randomNumber = getRandomNumber(-1000,1001);
            stringBuilder.append(randomNumber).append(" ");
        }
        txtpane1.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    }

    public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
    }
```

1. I have created a method that gives you a random number in range (-1000 to 1000).
2. I have removed the `ArrayList`. Instead, I have created a `StringBuilder` which will store all random numbers in it.
3. Modify the first Loop which will iterate till user input times (not till 1000 time) and in each iteration, it get the random number and append this random number to string builder.
4. Removed second loop, no need for it.
5. After then, just setting `StringBuilder` text in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the numbers like this.

```
Random r = new Random();
int n = r.nextInt(2001) - 1000;
```

- `r.nextInt(2001)` returns a number between `0 and 2000` inclusive.
- subtract `1000` from that and you get a number between -1000 and 1000 inclusive.

So you can use a loop to generate as many of those as you want.  You can also use a stream to generate the numbers and create the list.

- specify the number to generate and the range via `r.ints`
- map to an Integer and subtract `1000` as before.
- collect into a list.

```
int count = 10;
List<Integer> numbers = r.ints(count, 0, 2001)
        .mapToObj(i -> Integer.valueOf(i - 1000))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(numbers);
```

Prints something like

```
[586, 110, 667, 502, 129, -474, 382, -357, -906, -910]
```

imports required

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random()
final int min = -1000;
final int max = 1000;
// Map (-1000 to 1000) to ​(0 to 2001)
// because 'Random.nextInt' returns
// positive integers only.
final int positiveIntRangeMax = max - min + 1;
final int offsetFromPositiveIntRange = min;

​//loop 'a' times as required by user input
​for (int i=1;i<=a; i++) {
    ​int newPositiveRandInt = rand.nextInt(positiveIntRangeMax);
    ​int newRandIntInRange =
            ​newPositiveRandInt + offsetFromPositiveIntRange;
    ​list.add(newRandIntInRange);
​}

​txtpane1.setText(list.toString());
```

My attempt to get the random numbers.